# Spring HTTP 405 while trying ajax request

Tags: css, jquery, spring-mvc

I ahve a stange problem which is very specific to JSP and CSS i think. I am using Spring and jquery to post ajax request to server. In my JSP if i have following line -

```
<button class="btn-icon btn-small btn-grey btn-cross" onClick="delete('${ManagerVO.ContactInfoVO.branchId}');"><span>&#160;</span>Delete</button>
```

My code performes the operation but in the end i got HTTP 405 - Request method 'POST' not supported error. Now if i change above line to -

```
<input type="button" class="btn-icon btn-small btn-grey btn-cross" onClick="delete('${ManagerVO.ContactInfoVO.branchId}');"><span>&#160;</span>Delete</input>
```

code work perfectly well. jquery code is

```
function delete(Id) { $.ajax({
                    type: "POST",
                    url: "/XXX/XXX/XXX/delete",
                    data: "Id=" + Id,
                    success: function(errorVO){
                            alert(errorVO.errorText);                                           
                      },
                      error: function(e){
                          alert('Error, Please try later: ' + e);
                    }});}
```

and controller is -

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/delete", method = RequestMethod.POST)
    public @ResponseBody
    ResultVO delete(
            @RequestParam(value = "Id", required = true) String Id,
            Model model) {
        ResultVO resultVO = adminService.XXX(Id);
        return resultVO;
    }
```

Can someone please let me know how to fix this. I guess this is more of a CSS thing. firebug shosw me that default user angent css applied by crome is input type="button". Button CSS is as below -

```
.btn-icon
{
    background-repeat: repeat-x;
    color: #FFF;    
    font-weight: bold;
    display: inline-block;  
    text-decoration: none;
    border-width: 1px;
    border-style: solid;
    padding: 0 15px 4px;
    *padding: 0 7px 4px;
    margin: 0;
    text-shadow: 1px 1px 1px rgba(0,0,0,.2);
    -moz-box-shadow: 1px 1px 1px rgba(0,0,0,.25);
    -webkit-box-shadow: 1px 1px 1px rgba(0,0,0,.25);
    -moz-border-radius: 4px;
    -webkit-border-radius: 4px;
    filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.Shadow(color=#999999,direction=135,strength=2);
    cursor: pointer;
    position: relative;
}
```

Comment: i think it's more of a CSS issue, input type="button" has to be there. Only issue now is that image which was coming along with button text(value="blah") on my button is no longer displayed.....only button text(blah) is displayed :(

Answer (score 1):

I'm wondering if the `input` version is submitting the form perhaps (so you don't see the AJAX error).

Try changing the `onClick` attribute for both versions (input & button) to:

`onClick="delete('${ManagerVO.ContactInfoVO.branchId}'); return false;"`

and see what happens.

Comment: but then the issue is how would i redirect my request to actual controller, i have multiple buttons on my page :)

Comment: Not sure I understand your comment... the `return false` should ensure your AJAX gets triggered and NOT the form submit, which is what you want I think. AJAX doesn't (usually) change the page URL, it only updates parts of the page...